# Validation in asp.net MVC - validation only to happen when "asked"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I've got a slightly different validation requirement than the usual "when save, validate!".  The system can allow someone to update a bunch of times without being "bothered" with a validation listing UNTIL they say it's complete.  I thought I might be able to pull a fast one and put the [HandleError] on the method of which this would fire, but that validates every save.

Is there an attribte I can put into my custom validator that can handle this or am I going to have to write up my own HandleError attribute?

Comment: What validation framework are you using?

Comment: built-in, the filterattributes (what [HandleError] is based on) and data annotations ( [required] for instance)

Comment: The HandleError attribute has nothing to do with validation. Dataannotions doesn't have support for conditional validation. You could write your own implementations of the attributes to include it or use a framework that supports it (like fluent validation). But what should happen with the data when you submit it and you don't want to validate it. Should you still save it to the data store? Or do you want to save it temporary somewhere else?

Comment: save isn't fake or temporary, it saves it like it would any other time.  

There is a special event tied into "complete" -- seals it up, makes it uneditable and that's why I need the validation to occur "when asked"

Comment: What you need is conditional validation. Unfortunately dataannotions doesn't have support for that. My suggestion would be to switch to a validation framework that does (fluent validation being my favorite). Would that be a option?

Comment: probably not ... one thing I just noticed that if I clear out the modelstate just before it sends the info back, it scrubs those errors (along with everything else, useful stuff, like the data) ... wonder if there's a way to hijack that to clear JUST the errors?

Comment: Yes, you can clear just the errors. But I would consider that a hack. I would rather build out the validation framework to support conditional validation or move the validation from the modelbinder (or wherever you have it now) to the controller action instead and only run the validation when you should.

Comment: Right, I could do the ModelState.AddModelError(whatever) for each item, but that'd get messy.  Probably be best to move it out into its own service of sorts?  Maybe an interface with a validate() method on it and let that handle said validation... might be my best bet.